# Spring Interceptor does not fire

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have created an Interceptor for add some data to my controller responses.

I have a folder `com.project.Controllers` which hold all the controllers in my project,
And I want to intercept the response of each route inside this controller(InstituteController).

This is my Controller class(InstituteController):

```
@RestController
@Transactional
public class InstituteController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/institute/testInterceptor", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public BasicResponseModel testInterceptor(){
        BasicResponseModel basicResponseModel;
        basicResponseModel = new BasicResponseModel("Interceptor should get this message");
        return basicResponseModel;
    }
}
```

This is my Interceptor class:

```
@Aspect
public class AuthInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthInterceptor.class);

    @AfterReturning(pointcut="execution(* com.project.Controllers.InstituteController.*(..))", returning="result")
    public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint , Object result)  {
        if (result instanceof BasicResponseModel) {
            BasicResponseModel m = (BasicResponseModel) result;

            LOGGER.info("ActionResponse returned with message [{}]", m);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also add the Interceptor to the spring application on the configuration file:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addInterceptor(new AuthInterceptor());
    }

    //..........
}
```

I've also add the dependencies to the `pom.xml`:

```
        <!--
        AOP-START
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        AOP-START
        -->
```

The main purpose of this is to append an object or a key to the response like that.

This is the current response:

```
{
    "errorCode": 501,
    "errorName": "soem error msg",
    "customMessage": null,
    "object": null,
    "authUser": null
}
```

And I want to modify it by interceptor level to add another key to the object,

for example:

```
{
    "errorCode": 501,
    "errorName": "המוסד לא קיים במערכת.",
    "customMessage": null,
    "object": null,
    "authUser": null,
    "somekey": "new value"
}
```

I've no idea why the Interceptor is not fire when I use the institute controller.

Thanks!

Comment: One problem is you are mixing the use of `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` and AOP, you just need one of them.

Comment: Could you please confirm if the aspect is registered as bean ? Try adding `@Component` to your aspect and make sure this class is available in the component scan path

Comment: @R.G, adding `@Component` to the Interceptor class solve the problem, Thank you!